# Could Function randomly crashes with "Default Credentials" error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using Google Cloud Functions and in random cases, a function crashes returning:

> Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information.

How to handle this kind of error on pure Cloud Function (no Firebase) and is there a way to include key file (credentials)?

Comment: Hello, Cloud Support here. Given the nature of your question, I suggest for you to address it on the proper channels. If you have a support package, I would advise for you to open a ticket with Cloud Support so we can take a better look into it. If you don't have the support package, you can go to the Public Issue Tracker through [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=0) and post your issue there. Please confirm which option you are using.

Comment: @RodrigoC. I opened a ticket https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109894268